# Cut a figure along the x axis while retaining scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, xticks

I need to be able to compare graphs that show the progress of several variables over time. I need to do this for different cases, where the time covered is not always the same: now the data visualised covers 5 seconds long, then 10 seconds, then 30 seconds, etc.

The problem is that Matplotlib uses the number of seconds as a guide to determine the length of the graph -- meaning that a graph covering only 5 seconds will have the same length as one covering 30 seconds. See these two examples (NB: these are separate graphs, not subplots of the same graph):

[image: Graph covering 5 seconds]

[image: Graph covering 30 seconds]

In the [documentation for xlim](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html) I read that I can use it to turn autoscaling off, and I successfully did that. The upper graph now looks like this:

[image: Graph covering 5 seconds, scaled]

which is much better.

Is it now also possible to cut the graph off after 5 seconds, so that I don't have all that empty space at the end? Like this (NB: I faked this example with a graphics program and it's a little bit too small; it should be exactly 1/6 the size of the one above):

[image: Graph covering 5 seconds, scaled and cut]

Comment: (1) These are separate plots, not subplots, correct? (2) Please share reproducible code since adjusting `xlim` should do what you want.

Comment: @jared Yes, they are subplots. I've specified this in the question, which I changed since I found out why it didn't work in the meantime. (I've also changed the title to cover the question better.)

Comment: You said yes to being subplots in your comment but then your question says they're not "subgraphs". Which is it?

Comment: Yes you can do this.  However, it's not clear why, or what you want the final effect to be.  Do you want a ratio between two different axes eg comparing a 5 second axes to a 30 second axes?  Do you want 5 s to always be 1 inch wide?

Comment: @jared You are right, sorry, I messed up -- sorry for th confusion. What is in the question (corrected again just now) is right: they are NOT subplots, but separate graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a [`GridSpec`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html) instance. There are multiple ways to achieve what you want; here I'll use 2 rows, 2 columns, and use the `width_ratios` kwarg to control the size of the second subplot.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

gs = fig.add_gridspec(nrows=2, ncols=2, width_ratios=(1, 5), wspace=0)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, :])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])

ax1.set_xlim(0, 30)
ax2.set_xlim(0, 5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could define 6 columns, with equal width ratios, and then you could add subplots at any position along the x axis:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as pet

fig = plt.figure()

gs = fig.add_gridspec(nrows=4, ncols=6, wspace=0, hspace=0.35)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, :])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2, 3])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[3, 2:5])

ax1.set_xlim(0, 30)
ax2.set_xlim(0, 5)
ax3.set_xlim(15, 20)
ax4.set_xlim(10, 25)


plt.show()
```

[image]